# C# Failed to understand Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to validate a textbox to accept just alpha-numeric and `"\"` character, something like this:    `Testing123\` will return `true`.
Below is what I've tried so far:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*?$"
```

The above expression can accept alpha-numeric with no restriction of number of letters which working fine.

If not mistaken, `"\"` behave as escape character and so I tried below expression but it's throwing `unterminated expression` exception:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\]*?$"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're going to have to double-escape the backslash character because you actually need to send *two* backslashes to the Regex parser:

```
string example1 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\]*?$"; //two backslash characters assigned to the string
```

The first level of escaping is for the compiler, and the second level for the Regex - the backslash is an escape character, both in C# and Regex (that is, things like `\n` have meaning to the C# compiler and things like `\s` have meaning to the Regex parser)

Or you can use the `@` literal marker:

```
string example2 = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\]*?$" //same here but the @ symbol saves us the headache
```

---

Why you're seeing "unterminated expression" is the Regex parser sees `^[a-zA-Z0-9\]*?$` - that is, a beginning-of-line marker followed by a character class containing uppercase, lowercase, digits, and the characters `]`, `*`, `?`, `$`, which *is never closed because there's no closing bracket*.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, if now the case change to `?` instead of \ then the correct expression would be `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\?]*?$"` instead?

Comment: Yes and no: a)you don't need `/?` because it isn't an escape sequence and the compiler doesn't have a special meaning for `?`, so we're down to `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\?]*?$"`. And b)you actually don't need to escape the `?` once inside a character class, so sending a backslash to the Regex engine is superfluous, and you can simply use `"^[a-zA-Z0-9?]*?$"`

Answer (score 0):

Put one more back slash in your regular expression as shown below :

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\]*?$"
```

Comment: That's two more, and your answer been given by lc. Anyway, thanks for that :)

Comment: that's two more for the compiler perspective :)